# .map on array doesnt work (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, dictionary

I'm sure that this is an stupid question, but i cant find the answer. So, i have an array in which i want to add "}" to every element, so i'm using map.

```
zones.map {
      |z| z += '}'
    }
```

But it doesnt work. When i return the zones variable, nothign has changed. So, i was testing with simple arrays, and i find that in the irb this works, but not in the program?

So in the irb i did:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map { |z| z += "}" }
 => ["1}", "2}", "3}"]
```

Then the same in my code, and it doesnt work, when its the same:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map {
      |num| num+= "}"
    }
```

This returns

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

How can the same code work on irb but not on my code? i really dont understand anything of this, its the same code. Apart from that it seems like .map is not working with anything in my code.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code? In your code, if you add a line with "puts $yourvariable.class" what is the output? Is it an array?

Comment: Use `map!` instead of `map` to mutate `zones`

Comment: I doubt it's the same code you have. Can you show the full context where you use it? Please keep in mind that `.map` does not mutate the original array, it returns a copy if it and keeps the original intact. If you intend to mutate an array, take a look [Array#map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21).

Comment: @AbM The problem is not that he can't mutate his array, map should returns his array with the `}` concatenated without having to mutate the original. Actually @JuanMartinez I can't see why your code is not working. Do you use it in a specific context?

Comment: Okay i knew i was doing something wrong. First, i was calling in my code another variable wich had ["1", "2", "3"] in it, so even if i was changing something, i was printing other one. Second, i didnt know about map! lol  i thought map had the same behaviour. Its all fixed thank you very much.
edit: i cant see the way to upvote an answer or to mark one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments above, .map does not change the input variable, it simply shows what the result would be.

The correct option was .map!

Comment: `map` does not mutate the array, but one still can mutate elements. For example, with `z << '}'`. In this case there's no point in using `map`, of course. Can do with `.each`.